# React Native Business Card Scanner that i can plug in to my App

Tags: react-native

I was looking for an android Business Card Scanner project that I can integrate with my React Native App.Is there anything like that out there ?

Comment: have you got your solution

Answer (score 2):

I have written one like that which has all the logic to scan(OCR) and map the respective fields e.g Fname,Lname,designation,phone numbers etc but that was for native iOS and Android .

Checkout this [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.redmonk.bricapp.ocr&hl=en)

This runs on the engine I created, I used tesseract for OCR , react native wrapper for that is available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tesseract-ocr)